# Parse.com set class default attributes

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I have been working with Parse Cloud Code, and I have not achieved setting default values for my classes. Right now I am doing this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('MyClass',function(request, response){



 //The description should only have 200 characters
 if(request.object.get('description')){

   var des = request.object.get('description');

   if(des.length>200){
     request.object.set("description", des.substring(0, 197) + "...");
   }

 }


 //let's make a default value
 if(typeof request.object.get('active') === 'undefined'){
    request.object.set('active',false);
 }

 response.success();
});
```

When I upload this function to the Cloud Code, and try to create a new object from the dashboard it wont have the default value active = false.

I don't know what's going on. Has somebody achieved this before?

My code is very similar to the one in the Parse docs. They say this could be done like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Review", function(request, response) {
  var comment = request.object.get("comment");
  if (comment.length > 140) {
    // Truncate and add a ...
    request.object.set("comment", comment.substring(0, 137) + "...");
  }
  response.success();
});
```

However, for me it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 1):

Wohoo! I did it!

Nowhere in the documentation is said that if you want to do so, you must return the object you edited in the response.success().

Solution:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('MyClass',function(request, response){



 //The description should only have 200 characters
 if(request.object.get('description')){

   var des = request.object.get('description');

   if(des.length>200){
     request.object.set("description", des.substring(0, 197) + "...");
   }

 }


 //let's make a default value
 if(typeof request.object.get('active') === 'undefined'){
    request.object.set('active',false);
 }

 response.success(request.object); //this is the line that changes
});
```